# XCode not finding statically linked library

Tags: xcode, g++

Ok so I have an app that I'm writing that uses a library that someone at work developed. I've included the xcode project in my project and included the output target of that project in my project's target as a framework. I also included the .a file in my target under the "Link Binrary with Libraries" folder. I also have put in the configuration window the header and library search paths.

The problem is that when I try and build the project, it says that symbols are not defined in my project and xcode won't build it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if there is something that I'm missing.

btw... The library builds just fine on its own.

Thanks,
Robbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these things...

1- In the target you want to link the lib... Right click -> Get Info -> General Tab, and make sure that the lib is listed as a direct dependency.

2- Select the .xcodeproj in your groups and files window and make sure that you have the library product (should end in .a) checked.